# document search and retrieval from external file in python

Tags: python, search, file-io

I am trying to create a program that will search through articles that I have in a separate document. I am having trouble getting getting my program to search for the term and allow me to view the documents that contain only the search term. Ideally I want the search input to be something like moon, and allow me to access that document. The full document looks like this, and my code follows.

```
<NEW DOCUMENT>
Look on the bright 
side of Life.
<NEW DOCUMENT>
look on the very, dark
side of the Moon
<NEW DOCUMENT>
is there life
on the moon



search = input("Enter search words: ")
docs = []
document = []
doc_search = []

for line in file2:
    line = line.strip()
    if line == "<NEW DOCUMENT>":
        # start a new document
        document = []
        docs.append(document)
    else:
        # append to the current one
        document.append(line)
docs = ['\n'.join(document) for document in docs]

for line in docs:
    if line == search:
        doc_search = []
        doc_search.append(docs)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like this:

```
docs=[]
with open("data1.txt") as f:
    lines=f.read().split("<NEW DOCUMENT>")[1:]
    for x in lines:
        docs.append(x.strip())
    print (docs)
search = input("Enter search words: ")   
for x in docs:
    if search in x:
        print ("{} found in:\t {}".format(search,x))
```

**output:**

```
['Look on the bright \nside of Life.', 'look on the very, dark\nside of the Moon', 'is there life\non the moon']
Enter search words: dark
dark found in:   look on the very, dark
side of the Moon
```